# How to set timeout for StreamSocket.UpgradeToSslAsync in UWP apps?

Tags: c#, sockets, ssl, uwp

StreamSocket.ConnectAsync, ReadAsync and WriteAsync have overloads accepting CancellationTokenSource but not UpgradeToSslAsync. How can I overcome this? Or, is it made intentionally and timeout concept does not make sense for SSL handshake (at least in UWP apps) and I should simply rely on the default behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> StreamSocket.ConnectAsync, ReadAsync and WriteAsync have overloads accepting CancellationTokenSource

Actually, all the  [`ConnectAsync`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.networking.sockets.streamsocket.connectasync.aspx) overload methods of [`StreamSocket`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.networking.sockets.streamsocket.aspx) don't accept [`CancellationToken`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/system.threading.cancellationtoken(v=vs.105).aspx) parameter. Also, I didn't find `ReadAsync` and `WriteAsync` methods for `StreamSocket`. Commonly we use [DataReader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br208119) or [StreamReader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader(v=vs.110).aspx) for reading input stream of `StreamSocket`.

We can create a `CancellationToken` for the connection as you mentioned which is for timeout monitoring and canceling the connection. But we set this by [`WindowsRuntimeSystemExtensions.AsTask`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh779334(v=vs.105).aspx) method to represent the async action as task and then give a `CancellationToken`. Example code like follows:

```
socket = new StreamSocket();
HostName hostName = new HostName(host);
CancellationTokenSource _cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
_cts.CancelAfter(5000);
// Connect to the server
await socket.ConnectAsync(hostName, port).AsTask(_cts.Token);
return true;
```

So for [`UpgradeToSslAsync`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br226922) method you can also make it as task and give a `CancellationToken` as follows:

```
await socket.UpgradeToSslAsync(SocketProtectionLevel.PlainSocket, hostName).AsTask(cancellationToken);
```

Comment: My bad, looks like I mixed up StreamSocket methods and Stream methods. Now everything's clear, thanks.